# Drag and drop smaller images onto a larger image Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to drag and drop smaller images onto a background in android. In general a user would be able to select an object, say a ball, and drag and drop it onto the background. They should also be able to save this. What would be the easiest way to go about this? 
Thanks...

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. Dont expect people on SO to do your work for you.

Comment: I was hoping for some general ideas rather than someone to actually do the work.

Comment: So what's the real question then. How to implement a drag-function?

Comment: No, I have a rough idea how to implement "drag and drop" but more generally I'm stuck. Is it best to have an image and then drag other smaller images onto this "background"?

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: Would a canvas work?

Comment: Why not? You can also work with html5/js inside of a webview. I don't know what your requirements are. The *easiest* way to me would be to just move some views inside of a frame layout.

Comment: I was sort of wondering if there was an alternative or a nicer way to go about it.

Comment: Ok, I'll go with using canvas then. Thanks for your help